Change my name for a specific Teams meeting
I think I've seen this in some other collaboration/communication applications before: they just ask for your name before entering the meeting (maybe filling that field beforehand with your name if you are logged into an account)
In Teams I haven't found how to do this, and it's useful when it's several people inside a room who are speaking, and not only the one whose PC is providing the microphone. In that case, the name that Teams shows is misleading.
Is this possible in the desktop, web, or mobile apps?
